# F2051 Unit JclRegistry was compiled with a different version of System.UInt64

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, jedi

I'm implementing debugging with JEDI in my project. I added the ExceptionDialog with wizard, but when I'm trying the build project, I get

> F2051 Unit JclRegistry was compiled with a different version of System.UInt64

Comment: See http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=46671

Comment: I'd really recommend madExcept for this task